# If $(a_n)$ diverges, then when does it tend to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers. Consider the two points,

- 1.$\quad$     $(a_n)$ diverges,
- 2.$\quad$ $(a_n)$ [tends to **plus** infinity](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Divergent_Sequence_to_Infinity).

Using the fact that an unbounded sequence diverges, the second point implies the first one. What conditions should $(a_n)$ have to make first point to imply the second one? It seems obvious to me that $(a_n)$ has to be non-negative eventually or increasing eventually, but I do not know how to prove it.

**Example**: Let $(b_n)$ be a sequence of positive numbers, and define $s_N=\sum_{n=1}^{N}b_n$. If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ diverges, then it must be the case that $s_N\to\infty$ as $N\to\infty$, which is reasonable. But I want to know the proof. This is why I asked a question.

Comment: I don't think there's really a way to restate this better than the definition of tending to infinity.

Comment: For every $R>0$, you should be able to find an $N \geq 1$ so that $a_n \geq R$ whenever $n \geq N$.

Comment: Now that you edited point 2 with PLUS infinity: it is often stated in books that monotone divergent sequences tend either to plus or minus infinty. In this case you would just need $a_n$ to be non decreasing

Comment: $\lim \inf a_n = \infty$, but that is just paraphrasing point 2...

Comment: "has to be non-negative eventually" Yes. "or increasing eventually" No. Counterexample: $a_n=n+(-1)^n$.

Comment: @Did Could you please explain why to the first part?

Comment: There is basically no way of restating this that isn't circular; it suffices to say that $a_n$ would have to be monotonically increasing, but the justification depends on the definition you're trying to circumvent.

Comment: Could you please explain what I should explain in the first part?

Answer (score 1):

If $(a_n)$ is (weakly) increasing, then by the monotone sequence theorem it either converges to a finite value or diverges to $+\infty$. However, there are sequences that tend to $+\infty$ that are not eventually increasing, for example

$(a_n)=(1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5,4,5,6,5,6,7,6,7,8,...)$.

Comment: To the proposer: Another example: $a_{2n-1}=n$ and $a_{2n}=2^n.$

Answer (score 0):

"Eventually non-negative" is necessary but not sufficient.

"Eventually increasing" is not necessary and not sufficient.

"Unbounded" is necessary but not sufficient.

"Eventually increasing and unbounded" is not necessary but sufficient.

As said in comments, "larger than any number $u$ as of some $n(u)$" is the straightest requirement. This can also be phrased as "bounded below by an increasing unbounded function". (Intuitively, closer and closer to infinity.)

Comment: What does "necessary" and "sufficient" mean in terms of mathematical symbols? For example, does >"Eventually non-negative" is necessary but not sufficient< mean that "if $(a_n)$ is eventually non-negative and diverges, then $(a_n)$ tends to plus infinity" but "if $(a_n)$ is eventually non-negative and tends to plus infinity, then it does not diverge"?

Comment: @UnknownW: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency